Problem with IBM Installation Manager Download
If Download Director does not start install / re-install Download Director.  getting this again and AGAIN even after downloading. please help
i want to install ibm installation managaer in my system,have a look please help

Do your browser and/or Java install support launching IcedTea? Some JRE installs don't enable that option by default. Or the browser blocks the launch.
You should have an https download option in fix central if you dig around.
